# Create Thumb Image From UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

I'm using `WritableBitMap` to Create a Thumb Image From a UserContol but its not renderer correctly my image. The problem is that the `Width` and the `Height` of the UserControl is set to NAN.(I Think So)

Scenario:

- I Have a "Window" (UserControl) Navigator and need to create a list of opened Windows (UserControl) white a Thumb Image from each one, to show on a panel.
- Only current window is rendered correctly on thumb, other "windows" (UserControl) show all components in a "0,0" position because the current width and height of UserControl is not Defined (NaN).(I Think So)

Comment: I reall can't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ActualWidth` and the `ActualHeight` of the `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

> "Use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the UserControl."

The commentator above is right, but you need to get these values by using the `Dispatcher`, because it's always is zero.

Here is the sample:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>  
        {  
            //[your_control].ActualWidth;  
            //[your_control].ActualHeight;  
        });
```

Comment: thank's , but don't work , result is the same ActualWith =0 for a non rendered control.